# Git bare and non-bare repo

Tags: git

Im new on git, I am trying to push my website online.

On localhost :

```sh
git init
git add .
git commit -a
git remote add blabla ssh://blabla/project.git
git push babla master
```

On server side :

```sh
git init 
git pull blabla master
```

So the problem is, if my git on server is bare, I can't push. If my git server is non-bare, I can't pull...

```
remote: error: refusing to update checked out branch: refs/heads/master
remote: error: Par défaut, mettre à jour la branche actuelle dans un dépôt non-nu
remote: est réfusé parce que cela rendrait l'index et la copie de travail
remote: inconsistants avec ce que vous avez poussé et nécessiterait
remote: 'git reset --hard' pour réaligner la copie de travail avec HEAD.
```

on server :

```
fatal : this operation must be run on a work tree
```

Comment: Git will always complain of possible issues while trying to push to checked out branches. Please try `git init --bare`

Comment: I can push but I can't pull on server : operation mut be run in a work tree

Comment: You shouldn't pull on the server. You should push to it from your client, or temporarily clone a second copy on the server, pull into that copy and then push those into the bare repo.

Comment: I just noticed a typo in your push command. You seem to be pushing to `babla`, but the remote name you defined is `blabla`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a remote copy of the repository on your server, you can make that bare (so you can push to it) and create a none-bare clone of *that* repository where your web server can find it. In that case, you need two steps to deploy:

1. Push from your development machine to the bare repo.
2. Pull into the web server files from the bare repo.

You can automate the second step using a hook in the bare repo; probably the `post-update` hook but I'm not certain.

A simpler setup would be not to use git for deploying at all, and simply use rsync to copy the files to your web server.